# How do you run pry from emacs

Tags: pry

While writing RoR code I often need to run drop into a [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) session or a debugger. So I place my `binding.pry` line in the implementation code and run my spec(s). That works fine if I run the specs in a terminal but from inside Emacs, I get a messy output and it's very hard to use the debugger/pry.

How are you guys doing that ?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`rspec-mode` has recently added a [section in the README](https://github.com/pezra/rspec-mode/#debugging) on this subject. It says:

Install `inf-ruby` and add this to your init file:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'inf-ruby-switch-setup)
```

When you've hit the breakpoint, hit `C-x C-q` to enable `inf-ruby`.

Comment: That does work but unfortunately it has those weird color code characters like `^[[0G`, `^[[1A`. Can I get rid of those ?

Comment: For one of the escape codes, see the instructions at the bottom: https://github.com/nonsequitur/inf-ruby#bugs. If color codes also pose a problem (on my system, they don't), add `Pry.config.color = false` in the same manner as the fix suggested there.

Answer (score 6):

I find that [pry-remote](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote) is the best way to run pry within Emacs, since then pry gets its own dedicated buffer and can attach to a ruby process from anywhere (included a non-Emacs terminal or things like [pow](http://pow.cx/)). I use something like this:

```
(defun my-run-remote-pry (&rest args)
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer (apply 'make-comint "pry-remote" "pry-remote" nil args)))
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)
    (setq-local comint-process-echoes t)))

(define-key ruby-mode-map (kbd "C-c r d") 'my-run-remote-pry) ; (or whatever keybinding)
```

Then, you'll put `binding.remote_pry` in your code; you attach to a waiting `pry` with `C-c r d` (or whatever) and exit pry (continuing the process) with `C-c C-d`.

You'll also probably want to disable paging in your `~/.pryrc`, since it doesn't play well with `comint`:

```
Pry.config.pager = false
```